# Why is x*=y is slower than x=x*y in Python?

Tags: python, performance, assignment-operator

I am attempting to optimise some code I have written in Python and throughout I have assumed that it was more efficient (or in the worst case equivalent) in Python to write `x *= y` instead of `x = x * y`. But using the following basic test this does not appear to be the case

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
x = 1.01
for i in range(1000000):
    x *= 1.000001
print(time.time() - t0)
# Outputs 0.1081240177154541

t0 = time.time()
x = 1.01
for i in range(1000000):
    x = x * 1.000001
print(time.time() - t0)
# Outputs 0.07818889617919922
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Multiply the loop amount by 10 and run the test a few times and you'll see that the times will be almost the same

Comment: When I run this, the times differ by less than 1 part in 10000.
I suggest using a more reliable method, such as `timeit`.

Comment: To add to that: use can use timeit in a jupyter notebook and specify runs, and loops per run. For instance, 10 runs, 10 loops each: `%%timeit -r 10 -n 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been doing the fallowing tests:

```
def test1(x):
    for i in range(10000000):
        x *= 1.000001

def test2(x):
    for i in range(10000000):
        x = x * 1.000001


%timeit test1(1.01)
# 511 ms ± 25.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit test2(1.01)
# 591 ms ± 87.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

the difference it is so small that you could say that performance is the same

as my results show (the opposite of your conclusion) the results can differ from one machine to other or from one run to other

Comment: Thanks. How exactly did you use timeit to produce this output?

Comment: I use`timeit` from a jupyter notebook using python 3.7, from one run to the other the results are not the same

Comment: Can you do this in IDLE?

Comment: I wouldn't call an average speedup by 15% particularly small, especially for something this low-level.

Comment: look at the error +-25ms and +-87ms/ for 10 million iterations

Comment: Right, presumably we can run a larger benchmarks so that both averages are significant?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem 5.33 s ± 362 ms per loop  vs 5.4 s ± 223 ms (test1 vs tes2 ) for 100 mil iterations, hard to say something exactly

Comment: @PeterForeman same results in IDLE, very small difference  for 10mil, 5.0049 vs 5.0351 (test1 vs test2)

Comment: My guess is that `float.__rmul__` is doing some extra work in the background, although I cannot pin it down from the source. For example, `x *= 1j` turns `x` from a float to a complex (and changes `id(x)`). So presumably `float.__rmul__` runs some checks on both arguments that are redundant for `float.__mul__`.